# vb.net db application - deployment

Tags: vb.net, clickonce

developed a win. form vb.net db app that uses an access.accdb backend. I am struggling to find the best deployment strategy. In the past, I have distributed the .exe and access.accdb from the /bin/debug  folder. This works, but Im not sure if it's the best method.

1. this db app. will be used by 5-10 ppl, non-simultaneous
2. my current plan is to put the .exe and access.accdb on a network share drive, users will launch from network share
3. users do not have admin privs, the computers have **strict** security settings

I have noticed that when launching the .exe from network share, you get the unknown publisher warning; this message does not appear when launching from local drive. Due to users security restrictions, I know that simply hitting 'continue/run' on the publisher warning is NOT an option. There is no 'continue/run' button.

So, I assume I have to buy a code signing cert and strong name sign the assembly?

I also read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx that clickonce deployment does not require admin privs, and can be launched from network share and ran from cache.

In this case, I buy Authenticode cert and sign the clickonce manifest?

Any advice?

**edit**
I left out a key function of the app that will affect deployment.

Users can select files and upload them. The basePath/filename is stored in the db. uploading and retrieving the file via openFileDialog and datagridview.cellContentClick is all relative to where the .exe is launched from (application.startupPath). I didn't want to hard code full paths into the db, because I'm sure it will be moved, (both app and files) over time to a new location.

Comment: Can you put just the db file on the network share, give users a private copy of the .exe?

Comment: the app involves uploading files to a directory that's relative to application.startupPath, so I don't think this would work. the relative path is stored in the db.

Comment: Can you change the app? 'cause it seems like that is something that would be nice to be able to configure

Answer (score 0):

ClickOnce deployment is the way to go here.

You do not have to buy anything, you can [self sign your assembly with a strong name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms247123%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

This should be fine for an internal application