# VB.net compiler selection criteria

Tags: .net, vb.net, inno-setup

Good morning,

I am currently working on a mature VB.net application for commercial deployment and i have been asked to improve the installation process.

We are currently using Inno Setup, but based on my experience with webapps this seems like a over-complicated process. I had a look at clickonce, and this, [vb.net db application - deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428365/vb-net-db-application-deployment)

But any responses to VB.net installation seem to be over 18 months old, and Google searches seem to return many different options, but I cannot seem to find any unbiased review criteira or information.

My question is :
What are the criteria for judging a tool for building install packages for a VB.NET application?

Please feel free to recommend any applications (including Inno), but as I am new to VB.net the criteria for selecting the tool are the most important.

Ideally I would like an installation process which will allow 'live' updates on our users machine, but I think this will require significant reconfiguration on our part?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Any installer builder tool looks "overcomplicated" on first sight.  They do the kind of job that's pretty fundamentally different from what your normal programming tasks ever look like with OS details that tend to be pretty obscure.  You'll have to burn the time to learn how to use them, it is going to take more than a day.

Comment: If you do have enough time, please make sure you evaluate popular installer technologies, and then make up a report to ask yourself which is the simplest. By far, my personal opinion is that Inno Setup is probably the best you can get for free (simple, but also powerful). VB.NET desktop application deployment is nothing new (starting from day 1, year 2000), so I don't think seeing any article over 18 months old is a strange thing.

Comment: Do use the search feature, and don't limit yourself to questions dealing with VB.NET. Installers have been discussed countless times here on Stack Overflow. And any question dealing generally with .NET applications will have applicable answers, whether tagged C# or VB.NET.